# It is possible to made user-defined lookups filters by code on Lightning?

Tags: lightning, lookup-filter

I'm trying to make my Org Lightning Ready, and i notice that user-defined lookups filters (Lookups with optional filters) are not supported on Lightning.

If you leave the lookup filter as optional and active, on lightning it behave as required and that's not what i want.
So, there is any way to code an optional filter for a lookup field?